# Is CString more expensive than creating a CStr?

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm creating some C bindings in rust and some of the functions require `*const c_char` as an argument, but I don't know how it should be done in the most efficient way, does CString::new() create an allocation that CStr can avoid?

```rust
extern "C" fn foo(string: *const c_char) {
    // this function does not modify the string
}

fn main() {
    let arg = CString::new("hello").expect("error");
    unsafe { foo(&arg.as_ptr()) }
    // or
    let arg = CStr::from_bytes_with_nul(b"hello\0").expect("error");
    unsafe { foo(arg.as_ptr()) }
}
```

Comment: Use `CStr` if you can, because `CString` does allocate.

Comment: "`CString` is to `&CStr` as `String` is to `&str`: the former in each pair are owned strings; the latter are borrowed references." https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html

Comment: It would be unusual to get a `*const char` from C. You probably want `*const c_char` https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/type.c_char.html

Comment: It depends on the type of string you create. If you know the string at compile time, sure, use a `CStr`. But if you create the string during execution, then it has to live somewhere. This is where `CString` comes into play, because it provides storage for the string.

Comment: Worth pointing out also that you can't have a `CStr` referring to a regular `String` because `String`s in Rust don't include a terminating `NUL` character. Hence `CString` which is guaranteed to have the terminating `NUL` (and no other `NUL`s in the middle).

Comment: You can also use a crate to create a constant `&CStr` (there is also [an accepted RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3348-c-str-literal.html) for `c""` literals, but it was not yet implemented).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to everyone's comments I can conclude that `CStr`, like `str`, avoids an allocation but we can only use it when we know the value of the string at compile time, if the string is created during execution we need to use `CString`